# What is the big theta efficiency of ascii lookup in the angular compiler?

Tags: performance, angular, time-complexity, big-o

What I'm trying to determine is the lookup times of a capital letter as opposed to a lowercase. This leads me to ask if the lookup on the ascii table is Theta(1) or is it less efficient than that, meaning that capitals would have a faster lookup time than lowercases?

Comment: Can you please add the line of code whose performance you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, what do you mean by lookup? Also, both HTML and JavaScript use Unicode so what is this ASCII that you speak of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function's runtime is Θ(1), it means that the function always returns having done at least some work c1 and at most some work c2, where c1 and c2 are fixed constants. It doesn't mean that the runtime is always the same on all inputs.

In your case, the runtime of looking up whether a letter is a capital letter is indeed Θ(1), but that doesn't necessarily mean that the runtime for looking up upper-case or lower-case letters must be the same. It might be slightly faster to do one than the other.